# Civicrm Admin menu bar adding to a custom theme

Tags: drupal, theme

Was wondering whether anyone could shed some light on how to add the CiviCRM menu bar to a Drupal 7 customised theme (e.g. a theme built from scratch).  What javascript and parameters need to added to the tpl file to ensure the menu bar is rendered as required.

Thanks.

Comment: Is yours not showing up? I've never had to add anything specific to any of my themes in order for it to show up. Just going into the CiviCRM part of the site would make it pop up.

Comment: Hi Jenni thanks for taking the time to look at this.No the menu bars not showing up - but, someone else created the template being used and in all fairness the drupal menu bar is also now showing when a user logins as an admin user.  And the print page_top line is in the template output file.

Comment: I'll see about pulling my files for one of my themes and posting it below. I'll try to get to that in the next couple days (I'm not at my work computer right now). It's possible they are specifying specific javascript files or something instead of just telling it to put the script files in and allowing CiviCRM (and other modules) to insert their files as needed.